# codeigniter mcrypt and don't create_iv

Tags: php, codeigniter, decode, mcrypt

I am using codeigniter 2x, and I need to decode string I have been given, and that string containes array. For that I got a key, iv, cipher and mode.

I figure out how to set key, cipher and mode:

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');
$this->encrypt->set_cipher(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128);
$this->encrypt->set_mode(MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$key = 'mysomekey';
```

But I can't figure out how to use iv I have been give, and decode that string.

On net I did found only this:

```
$o = $this->encrypt->decode($o,$key);
```

Can anyone helps me?

Answer (score 0):

From the [mcrypt docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php) you can provide all the input parameters in the decrypt call:

```
string mcrypt_decrypt ( string $cipher , string $key , string $data , string $mode [, string $iv ] )
```

It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data.

Codeigniter provides it's own [Encryption Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/encryption.html).

Also consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Comment: I have some requirements I have to achive, that's why I am using mcrypt. I saw this but doesn't work. And I have to write as codeigniter sintax using library also.